# Why do microphones get loud when loading Starcraft?

Tags: starcraft-2, skype

I use Skype a lot while playing Starcraft 2, and for many people that I've skyped with, their microphones go extra loud when a map/game is loading.

Sometimes the reverb-like sound gets so loud you have to mute your headset.

I would think it might be the hard drive or the graphics card pulling extra power, but I haven't noticed it during times of intense graphics during a game.

Comment: Since SC2 has built-in voice chat (which noone uses), it might be that the Blizzard Programmers were lazy and bound the ingame microphone volume to the system volume and/or set the microphone boost in the system instead of using an ingame boost.

Comment: Funny you ask this, my friend just mentioned that yesterday. XD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in SC2 when using a Realtek soundcard.

Here are [two](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/3811454597) [threads](http://eu.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/3225586710) on battle.net from users experiencing the exact same problem.  The issue seems to be that, when Starcraft II first starts up or first loads a map, it sometimes arbitrarily changes your mic volume and mic-boost settings to whatever it feels like.  The reason it doesn't last is that Skype is smart enough to reduce the volume again when it detects how loud it is.

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ixeuiERtMO0) is an ironically quiet video demonstrating the issue.  The [thread that video comes from](http://www.sc2sea.com/showthread.php?t=3769) has a potential solution, which seems to work for some but not others:

> - Open your in-game options and go to the Voice tab. Here’s the settings your game uses to interact with the mic.
> - Change the Settings in the Talking section (you’ll need to Enable Talking first if it’s not already):
>     [image: SC2 mic settings]
>
>   - Select the correct Input Device (default device will be picked by default).
>   - Adjust the microphone volume to whatever you want your mic set at.
>   - Uncheck everything (unless you actually use the Voice Chat).

---

As a side-note, that same thread also has a solution for another annoying problem us skyper's face:  when starting a game during a call, skype *(Actually, it's Windows)* will sometimes reduce that game's volume.

The solution is to change the setting under control panel --> sound --> communications

[image: sound settings]